# 'Entitlement Task Notificiations' : Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: scheduled-apex

Scheduled job 'Entitlement Task Notificiations' threw unhandled exception.

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.opentasks.doJob: line 40, column 1
Class.opentasks.execute: line 4, column 1

```
global class opentasks Implements Schedulable {

    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) {
        doJob();
    }

    public void doJob() {
        List<RecordType> recType = [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE name = 'Entitlement Task' AND sobjecttype = 'Task' AND IsActive = TRUE limit 1];
        List<messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmails = new List<messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        Set<Id> users = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> etermIds = new Set<Id>();
        String Sub;
        List<Task> tasklistToday = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> tasklistMonday = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> tasklistMonthly = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> tasklistOverdue = new List<Task>();
        Integer daysInMonth = date.daysInMonth(system.today().year(), system.today().month());
        Date weekStart = system.today().toStartofWeek();
        Integer dayOfWeek = weekStart.daysBetween(system.today());
        Boolean Monday = dayOfWeek == 1;
        Boolean firstOfMonth = (system.today().Day() == 1);
        Integer daysBetween;
        DateTime activityDate;
        Date taskDate;
        Date today = System.today();
        String todaystring = today.format();
        Boolean futureTask;

        list<Task> open1 = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhoId, WhatId, ActivityDate, AssignedToEmailAddress__c,
                            Subject, Status, RecordTypeId, What.Name, Receive_Entitltement_Emails__c,
                            No_Daily_Task_Emails__c, No_Monthly_Task_Emails__c, No_Weekly_Task_Emails__c, No_Overdue_Task_Emails__c
                            FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND RecordTypeId = :recType[0].Id
                            AND (ActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30 OR ActivityDate = NEXT_N_DAYS:30)
                            ORDER BY OwnerId, ActivityDate, Subject];
        //system.debug('XXXX open1 size ' + open1.size());

        for (Task t :open1) {
            // only care about Tasks for Entitlement Terms
            if (String.valueof(t.WhatId).substring(0, 3) == 'a0Y') {
                users.add(t.OwnerId);
                etermIds.add(t.WhatId);                
            }
        }

        Map <Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c> eterms = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c>([SELECT Id, Reference_Information__c, SpecialTrunc__c,  ET_Plant__c, ETCustomerNumber__c FROM sm1e__smCObject_B__c WHERE Id IN :etermIds]);
    List<Attachment> docs = new List<Attachment>([SELECT Id, ParentId, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :etermIds AND Name Like 'Task Attachment%' ORDER BY Id]);        
        Map <Id, Attachment> etermDocs = new Map<Id, Attachment>();
        for (Attachment a :docs)
            etermDocs.put(a.ParentId, a);
        //system.debug('XXXX users ' + users.size() + ' eterms ' + eterms.size() + ' docs ' + docs.size() + ' etermDoc ' + etermDocs.size());

        for (Id uid :users) {
            tasklistOverdue.clear();
            tasklistMonday.clear();
            tasklistMonthly.clear();
            tasklistToday.clear();
            for (Task t :open1) {
                activityDate = t.ActivityDate.addDays(1);
                taskdate = activityDate.date();
                futureTask = (taskdate >= today);
                if (futureTask) {
                    daysbetween = today.daysbetween(taskdate);
                }
                if (t.OwnerId == uid) {
                    If (today == taskdate && !t.No_Daily_Task_Emails__c)
                        tasklistToday.add(t);
                    If (today > taskdate && !t.No_Overdue_Task_Emails__c)
                        tasklistOverdue.add(t);
                    If (Monday && futureTask && daysbetween < 7 && !t.No_Weekly_Task_Emails__c)
                        tasklistMonday.add(t);
                    If (FirstOfMonth && futureTask && daysbetween < daysInMonth && !t.No_Monthly_Task_Emails__c)
                        tasklistMonthly.add(t);
                }
            }

            if (tasklistToday.size() > 0) {
                Sub = 'NOTIFICATION: Due Today ' + todaystring;
                buildemails(tasklistToday, eterms, allmails, Sub, etermDocs);
            }
            if (tasklistMonday.size() > 0) {
                Sub = 'NOTIFICATION: Due This Week ' + todaystring;
                buildemails(tasklistMonday, eterms, allmails, Sub, etermDocs);
            }
            if (tasklistMonthly.size() > 0) {
                Sub = 'NOTIFICATION: Due This Month ' + todaystring;
                buildemails(tasklistMonthly, eterms, allmails, Sub, etermDocs);
            }
            if (tasklistOverdue.size() > 0) {
                Sub = 'NOTIFICATION: Past Due ' + todaystring;
                buildemails(tasklistOverdue, eterms, allmails, Sub, etermDocs);
            }            
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(allmails);
    }

    public static void buildemails(List<Task>tasklist, Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c> eterms, messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emails, String Sub, Map<Id, Attachment> etermDocs) {
        String[] toAddresses,bccAddresses;
        //system.debug('XXXX buildemails email ' + tasklist[0].AssignedToEmailAddress__c);
        //system.debug('XXXX buildmails tasks,terms,sub ' + tasklist + ' ' + eterms + ' ' + Sub);
        // if the user is not receiving emails, send them to admin for now while we test
        if (tasklist[0].Receive_Entitltement_Emails__c)
            toAddresses = new String[] {tasklist[0].AssignedToEmailAddress__c};
        else
            toAddresses = new String[] {'john.reed@powerfactorscorp.com'};
        messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        bccAddresses = new String[] {'john.reed@powerfactorscorp.com','steve.hanawalt@powerfactorscorp.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses);
        mail.setReplyTo('support@powerfactorscorp.com');
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D216000000L6O9');
        mail.setSubject(Sub + ' for ' + tasklist[0].AssignedToEmailAddress__c);
        String body = getTableEmailBody(tasklist, eterms, Sub, etermDocs);
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        emails.add(mail);            
    }

    public static string getTableEmailBody(List<Task> tsks, Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_B__c> eterms, String Sub, Map<Id, Attachment> etermDocs) {
        Datetime due;
        Date dateDue;
        String htmlBody;
        Boolean futureTask;
        Attachment a;
        String Entitlement_Term_Prefix = Schema.SObjectType.sm1e__smCObject_B__c.getKeyPrefix(),taskWhatId;

        htmlBody = '<table border="2" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="font-size:9px; font-family:sans-serif; background-color:#FFFFFF" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >';
        htmlBody += '<caption>' + Sub + '</caption>';
        htmlBody += '<tr><th>Plant #</th><th>Plant Name</th><th>Subject</th><th>Reference Information</th><th>Status</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Link to Term</th><th>Completion Variance (Days)</th><th>Special Instructions (Truncated)</th><th>Link to Attachment</th></tr>';

        for(Task t : tsks) {           
            if (t.WhatId != null) {
                taskWhatId = t.WhatId;              
                if(taskWhatId.startsWith(Entitlement_Term_Prefix)) {
                    due = t.ActivityDate.AddDays(1);
                    String dt =  due.format('M/d/yy');
                    dateDue = t.ActivityDate;
                    futureTask = DateDue >= system.today();
                    Integer daysBetween = system.today().daysBetween(dateDue);                  
                    sm1e__smCObject_B__c etermr = eterms.get(t.WhatId);
                    a = etermDocs.get(t.WhatId);
                    htmlBody += '<tr><td>' + etermr.ETCustomerNumber__c + '</td><td>' + etermr.ET_Plant__c + '</td><td>' + t.Subject;
                    htmlBody += '</td><td>' + etermr.Reference_Information__c + '</td><td>' + t.Status + '</td><td>' + dt;
                    htmlBody += '</td><td>' + '<a href="https://na23.salesforce.com/' + t.WhatId + '">' + t.What.Name + '</a>' + '</td>';
                    htmlBody += '<td style="font-weight:bold; color:';
                    if (daysBetween <= 0)
                        htmlBody += '#ff0000';
                    else
                        htmlBody += '#66CD00';
                    htmlBody += '">' + daysBetween + '</td>';
                    htmlBody += '<td>' + etermr.SpecialTrunc__c + '</td>';
                    if (a != null)
                        htmlBody += '<td>' + '<a href="https://na23.salesforce.com/' + a.Id + '">' + a.Name + '</a>' + '</td>';
                    else
                        htmlBody += '<td>(N/A)</td>';
                    htmlBody += '</tr>';
                }
            }   
        }        
        htmlBody += '</table>';
        return htmlBody;
    }
}
```

This Schedule job runs everyday. But we received the unhandled exception error only yesterday. what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is giving you error.

```
if (String.valueof(t.WhatId).substring(0, 3) == 'a0Y') {
```

because if any of your task dosen't contain `whatId` then you will get null pointer exception so you need to update your condition and put a null check. You might also need to add this null check in all place where you are using this field.

```
if (t.WhatId != null && String.valueof(t.WhatId).substring(0, 3) == 'a0Y') {
```

Comment: worked. thank you